# perl function to replace all spaces in file and directory names with periods

Tags: perl

I'm not a programmer by trade so I just wanted to put that disclaimer out there. And there is probably a better way of doing this but this is the way I started and I'd like to know why this isn't working.

I have a perl function for replacing spaces with periods in filenames and directories:

```
sub rm_space {
    for(@_) {
    # for directory or file if it contains spaces, replace with periods
        chomp;
        if(m/^(.*(.(?=\s).).*)$/) {
            $new = $_;
            $new =~ s/ /\./g;
            move($_, $new);
        }
        if(-d) {
        # if $_ is a directory, list contents and repeat
            @arr = `ls -1d $_/*`;
            rm_space(@arr);
        }
    }
}
```

The function will work on everything in the first array (@_) but will not work recursively on the second unless the directory from the first array didn't already contain spaces.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between yours and mine? ... also that portion isn't the problem.

Comment: You're right. But now I think I spotted the error: in the first `if` you rename a directory from `dir 1` to `dir.1` and then do an `ls -1d dir 1`, i.e. with the old name. But that directory no longer exists. Plus: `ls -1d dir 1` won't work if the directory name has spaces in it. Don't you get any errors?

Comment: I don't get errors and yes I thought that too. So does the first move($_, $new) not take immediate effect? Because I thought that when the second if was evaluated the directory would be renamed and reflected in the second array. I'm assuming that's not the case and am wondering if I could make it so.

Comment: The `-d` still works on the magic/hidden/automatic variable `$_` and that hasn't changed. Hold on.

Comment: Is `$new =~ $_;` a typo?

Comment: yeah it is, thanks, but isn't in the actual code

Comment: I updated it ... it was just that typo Jim Davis pointed out.

Comment: oh, I got it ... thanks perlduck .. your comment about the default variable not having changed made me realize my mistake.

Comment: Did you figure it out already?

Comment: @PerlDuck yes, I can. If it's just one line, you should fix it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process files recursively in Perl, use [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

my %rename;
find(\&spaces2dots, shift);
for my $old (sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %rename) {
    rename $old, $rename{$old}
        or warn "Cannot rename $old to $rename{$old}.\n";
}

sub spaces2dots {
    ( my $new = $File::Find::name ) =~ s{ (?!.*/)}{.}g;
    $rename{$File::Find::name} = $new;
}
```

The files are sorted by filename length starting from the longest one, and only spaces after the last `/` are replaced in each step, so file named `a b/c d/e f` is renamed to `a b/c d/e.f`, then its parent directory is renamed to `a b/c.d`, and finally the `a b` directory is renamed to `a.b`.

For completeness, here's the Makefile I used for testing:

```
run: clean
    mkdir 'a b' 'c d'
    mkdir 'a b'/'A B' 'a b'/'C D'
    mkdir 'a b'/'C D'/'e F'
    touch 'e f' 'a b'/'E F' 'a b'/'C D'/'e F'/'g H'
    40115711.pl .
    find

clean:
    rm -rf ???
```

Comment: I thought I had it but I didn't your example seems to be the best. Thanks for simplifying it for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub rm_space
{
    foreach my $file_or_dir (@_) {

        my $with_dots = $file_or_dir;
        if ( $with_dots =~ tr/ /./ ) {
            # only called when replacement occurred
            rename( $file_or_dir, $with_dots );
        }

        if ( -d $with_dots ) {
            my @arr = glob("$with_dots/*");
            rm_space(@arr);
        }
    }
}

rm_space( glob("start_dir/*") );
```

You first renamed a directory from e.g. `dir with spaces` to `dir.with.spaces` but then dive into
`dir with spaces`. That directory already has gone. You need two variables, one for the old name
and one for the new one, and then call `rm_space` on the new name.

Also it's strongly recommended to `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to avoid common errors (like typos
or usage of undefined variables).

I replaced the call to `ls` with a call to `glob`. The advantage is that you don't have to care about
spaces in names then. Your `ls -1d dir with spaces/*` must have failed.

I also used explicit variables (as opposed to the implicit `$_`) because it's sometimes hard to figure out
what `$_` actually contains.